# Using HTTPPost2 AMPScript function with special characters (like ñ or accents)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to inject a contact in Journey Builder using AMPScript and I'm using HttpPost2 method, but I'm finding that this function doesn't allow to add Spanish characters like 'ñ' or 'á'. I've tried to add encoding parameters but it doesn't work. If check it out using PostMan and it works well. Any help would be really appreciated.

PS: This is the payload is sent by HTTPPost2 function:

```
{
    "ContactKey": "sfmc.demo.co@gmail.com",
    "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-23c9a842-1214-c2cc-8a3c-34b9c4ab7a7c",
    "Data": {
        "Nombre": "Ángel",
        "Apellidos": "Muñoz",
        "eMail": "sfmc.demo.co@gmail.com",
        "Movil": "34673641929"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed!

When using HTTPPost2 you should replace special characters for Unicode code like \u00e1 = á

Regards